# Error detected while processing ~/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/pymode/lint.vim

Tags: error, plugin-python-mode

I followed a tutorial toon vim setup and used wget to load someone's .vimrc .

On opening a file with vim, i get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing function pymode#breakpoint#init
line 29:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named six
```

This is then followed by

```
Error detected while processing /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/pymode/lint.vim    
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/py
mode/lint.vim:
line    1:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/py
mode/lint.vim:
line    1:
  File "/home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/pymode/lint.py", line 9, in <module
>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/py
mode/lint.vim:
line    1:
    from pylama.lint.extensions import LINTERS
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing /home/bridge/c/sheth7/.vim/bundle/python-mode/autoload/py
mode/lint.vim:
line    1:
ImportError: No module named pylama.lint.extensions
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

my `vim --version:`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jul  9 2019 02:33:15)
Included patches: 1-207, 209-629
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/etc"
 f-b for $VIMRUNTIME: "/usr/share/vim/vim74"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lnsl  -lselinux  -ltinfo -lacl -lattr -lgpm   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE  -fstack-protector  -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE -lperl -lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

Comment: Yeah, but **which** errors are you getting at startup? It's hard for us to guess if you don't tell us...

Comment: These "ans associated errors" would be quite useful. The most likely cause is that some package update did not happen correctly. Purge vim.

Comment: Added error info to the question

Comment: @sheth7 welcome to [vi.se]! Unfortunately, you’re question is a little unclear. We dont know what your vimrc or .vim directory looks like, we dont know what tutorial you followed, and it’s going to be hard for *us* to debug that way. If you can, [edit] in some more information to help us find the problem. Aside: this is just one more reason i don’t recommend people to copy others’ vim configs. A line or two is fine, if you understand it and why you want it, but a setup wholesale is just going to be more confusing for you.

Comment: In the meantime, also checkout https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604 for some debugging tips.

Comment: @D. Ben - Here is the link to the github repo for the tutorial - https://github.com/thesheff17/youtube/tree/master/vim. 

I used the vimrc2 file and created the .vim folder stucture as shown in the vim-notes.txt file

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in Python code, importing a Python module.

This is a Python stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named six
```

You need to install the Python [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/) module in your machine, in order to get past this error.

There are quite a few ways to install Python modules on a host (`pip` or native package managers such as `apt-get`, `yum` or `dnf`, you can install it for Python 2 or Python 3, for your user only or system-wide), so it's hard to tell which option is right for you without knowing more details on your environment.

But now that you know what the issue is (missing Python module), you can try to search for answers related to that, you'll probably find one that's right for you.

Comment: Thanks filbranden. I am working on a shared server. I have a conda virtual environment that I use on the server that has package 'six'. The server has python 2 and 3 and has package 'six' installed as well. So for some reason, it is not able to detect the package. How can I go about debugging this?
Also, if it helps to know - opening any other file (.txt etc) besides a .py does not generate the error.